# Printing 3 year calendar in months staring from the current month

Tags: javascript

I am getting the current date in javascript and then I convert it to the current month. Based on the current month (9 now), I want to print the month calendar for the last 3 years backwards. So, if we have September 2013, the following has to be printed:

`08 09 10 11 12   2010`
`01 02  03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12   2011`

`01 02  03  04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12  2012`

`01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08         2013`

I have a general idea how to print the first line, but I'm struggling how to print the rest of the calendar. Here is my code for the first line (2013):

```
function printCalendarRows(){
        var d = new Date();
        var n = (d.getMonth()) + 1;
        var twelve = 12;
        for(var i = n; i <= 12; i++){
            for(var j = 12; j >= n; j--){
                console.log(i);
                console.log(j);
            }
        }
}
```

Any recommendations? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is what you want

```
function printCalendarRows(){
        var d = new Date();
        var o = new Date();
        o.setMonth( (d.getMonth()) - 36); //or   o.setFullYear( (d.getFullYear()) - 3);
        var currnt;
        while (o < d)
        {
          currnt = o.getMonth();
          console.log(currnt);
          if (currnt == 11)
          {
             console.log(o.getFullYear());
          }
          o.setMonth(currnt+1);

        }
        if (d.getMonth() != 11)
        {
           console.log(d.getFullYear());
        }
        alert("Date:"+ d + "Month:" + d.getMonth());
}
```

Comment: Just checked it on a jsfiddle and it's not working... http://jsfiddle.net/BLwYM/ So we are getting 2 different dates here. Is the second one for the year?

Comment: This is my Console Output 8
9
10
11
2010
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
2011
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
2012
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
2013. Did you got this?

Comment: No, I didn't. It seems that I have an issue with console.log. It doesn't even print a statement on my browser. Thanks though mate!

Comment: Please check with my updated code. You fiddle is having my older code

Comment: Yeah, it works perfect as an alert now. I don't know what's wrong with the console.log or anything else. Thank you my friend for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function calRows() {
    var date,
        now = new Date(),
        str = "";

    for (var i = -37;i++;) {       
        date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + i - 1, 1)
        month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        str += month + " " + (+month % 12 == 0 ? date.getFullYear() + "\n" : "")
    }

    return str + date.getFullYear();
}
console.log (calRows()) /*
08 09 10 11 12 2010
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 2011
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 2012
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 2013 */
```

Heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8bwm/1)

Or if you prefer, the same without assigning a new Date object in the loop.

```
function calRows() {
    var date,
        now = new Date(),
        first = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() -37, 1),
        monthYear = [first.getMonth(),first.getFullYear()]
        str = "";

    for (var i = -37;i++;) {
        month = ("0" + (++monthYear[0])).slice(-2);
        str += month + " " + (+month % 12 == 0 ? (monthYear[0]=0,monthYear[1]++) + "\n" : "")
    }

    return str + monthYear[1]
}
```

Comment: Why was the last rev upvoted ? I did set `now = new Date()` in the *loop* that didn't made any sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/):

```
function printCalendarRows(){
    var d = moment().subtract('months', 37);
    var y = d.format("YYYY");
    var n = moment().format("MM/YYYY");
    var log = "";
    while(d.format("MM/YYYY") != n) {
        if (d.format("YYYY") != y) {
            console.log(log + y + "\r\n");
            y = d.format("YYYY");
            log = "";
        }
        log += d.format("MM") + " ";
        d = d.add("months", 1);
    }
    console.log(log + d.format("YYYY"));
}

printCalendarRows();
```

[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tetri/dTgNK/)